# Force slash htaccess in a specific case

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I'm trying to force a slash at the end of an url.

```html
#i want this url https://example.com/it/parameter/
#with the slash

RewriteRule ^it/([a-z]+)/?$ it_page.php?p=$1 [L]


#and this rewrite too
#i want this url https://example.com/it/parameter/par1-mod-par2 
#without slash at the end

RewriteRule ^it/([^/]+)/(.+)\-mod\-(.+)$ it_page.php?p=$1&q0=$2&r=$3 [L]
```

Because with this code when i enter : https://example.com/it/parameter it's not redirected to https://example.com/it/parameter/
so it creates a duplicate content.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on
#Enforce a trailing slash on URIs with specific format `/it/perameter`
RewriteRule ^it/[^/]+$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
#RewriteRules
RewriteRule ^it/([a-z]+)/$ it_page.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^it/([^/]+)/(.+)-mod-([^/]+)$ it_page.php?p=$1&q0=$2&r=$3 [L]
```